# Where to start de-verb from ? I don't see any shortcut

Tags: audio, audio-recording, screencasts, digital-audio

I was recording some of the screencasts and there was some reverb in the audios of those videos. Than I searched online and found that the reverb can be eliminated or decreased by using a software named `de-verb`. Than I downloaded that software from [this link](http://spl.info/produkte/analog-coder-plug-ins/microplugs/de-verb.html) , installed it. But now when I saw there is not shortcut or executable file inside program files from where I start the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De-verb is a plugin, not a standalone application.

It requires a Host to run in, something capable of running RTAS, VST, or AU.

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features) (freeware) can run VST & AU plugins.
Some Video editors can too, but I don't know which ones on Windows, other than what Google could tell me - such as [Magix Movie](http://www.magix.com/us/movie-edit-pro/detail/functions/) - though I have no idea whether it's any good or not.

Comment: Though this information is not 100% enough for me, but as you told me that de-verb is a plugin not an app and it also works in audacity. Thank You for that. I was gonna vote your answer up, but don't have enough reputation (as the site told) !

Comment: Plugin & host spec itself is a huge subject of its own, & would quickly get closed as off-topic in here; you might ask on one of the other SE sites for more specifics - possibly [Sound Design](http://sound.stackexchange.com) or [Video Production](http://video.stackexchange.com)

Comment: No, i already get the plugin working in Audacity (one of my favorite audio editing programs), Thank You. I'm gonna accept the question.